# Return Html ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

below is my code to fetch a webpage html....

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'server.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType : "html",
    data: {name: 'film'},
    success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
    });
});
```

server.php wil return ...

```
return <div>some html contents</div>
```

I want to show this in ajax console success function....now its not displaying anything in `console`.. how do we fix this....

Comment: Do not return `html content`, echo it..

Comment: @RayonDabre that will solve the problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to @Rayon Dabre , As he mentioned, I have solved the problem.... by writing `echo <div>some html contents</div>` instead of `return <div>some html contents</div>`

Comment: i can read in comment that @Rayon suggested the answer it is proper to give him the credit